# How to get a user string input on Telepot?

Tags: python, heroku, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm new in Python and in Telegram bot, I hope you can help me understand this with a simple example.
What I need is to define a method that returns me a string to complete a url.
In Python what I need is:

```
user = input("Insert a username to see the graph:")
graphUrl = "https://www.graphsss123.com/ser/graph/" + user + "-123.jpg"
print(graphUrl)
```

how could I get the same result using Telepot?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no exclusive function for receiving messages in telepot(I guess!!),so you will have to maintain the states (here i have done that using step).The snippet below is an example for adding 2 numbers given by user through telegram
ref:https://github.com/nickoala/telepot/issues/209

```
global step, no1
        if step == 1:
            if msg['text'] == 'add':
                bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "input no1")
                step = 2
            else:
                bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "please provide no")
        elif step == 2:
            no1 = msg['text']
            bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "input no2")

            step = 3
        elif step == 3:
            no2 = msg['text']
            no3=no1+no2
            bot.sendMessage(chat_id,no3)
            step = 1
```